# CSS style not getting applied on JSF page

Tags: css, jsf, jsf-2

I have created a new css file and added the following style in it:

```
.op-label {
    color: orange;
}
```

I've placed this file 'hms.css' in

> "/webapp/resources"

folder.

I've included this in my JSF template file BasicTemplate.xhtml as follows:

```
<h:head>
    <title><ui:insert name="title">Basic Template</ui:insert></title>
    <h:outputStylesheet name="hms.css"/>
</h:head>
```

Here is how I am using this style with my output component in my faces page:

```
<p:outputLabel value="First Name" styleClass=".op-label"></p:outputLabel>
```

**Issue**: The style is not applied on the rendered html.  Rendered html code snipped it below:

```
<head>

    <link href="/HMSWeb/javax.faces.resource/theme.css.xhtml?ln=primefaces-sunny" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
    <link href="/HMSWeb/javax.faces.resource/hms.css.xhtml" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
    <link href="/HMSWeb/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.css.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=4.0" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
    <script src="/HMSWeb/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=4.0" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/HMSWeb/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery-plugins.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=4.0" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/HMSWeb/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=4.0" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <title> … </title>

</head>
```

**Question**: What is the reason for this?  Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: should be `styleClass="op-label" `

Comment: Not sure about jsf but I don't think you should be using a period here `styleClass=".op-label"`

Comment: @user876345, your suggestions worked.  Thank you very much!

Comment: @Phantom Reference, Glad to help you. Added my solution in answer section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `styleClass="op-label"`

```
 <p:outputLabel value="First Name" styleClass="op-label"></p:outputLabel>
```

instead of

```
 <p:outputLabel value="First Name" styleClass=".op-label"></p:outputLabel>
```

Answer (score 1):

As user876345 has suggested, removing the period should to the trick.  So, it should be like:

```
styleClass="op-label"
```

instead of

```
styleClass=".op-label"
```

Answer (score -1):

Just try with putting complete  URL in the source. For Ex:-

http://www.knowtheworld.in/ ..path to your css /HMSWeb/javax.faces.resource/hms.css.xhtml

Answer (score -1):

Just try with putting complete URL in the source. For Ex:- http://www.theclickus.com/

Comment: PS: stack exchange renders links with `rel="nofollow"`.